# Can home brewer co-locate in a microbrewery? (Oregon)

Tags: legal

A friend has a small brewery in Oregon with lots of extra space. I'd love to be able to do my tiny home brewing over there, as I have no room at home and he has room to spare. There's no desire or intent to cross the line on selling any homebrew; just a desire to use better space for free. Anyone know if this might be legally OK?

*(I'm in Oregon, so OLCC is the state agency --- nothing obvious on their site or on the interwebs).*

Comment: Can you say why you think it might not be ok?

Comment: I am not the OP, but I could speculate.  In the United States, there is typically a 100 or 200 gallon limit to homebrewing before a tax kicks in (which may vary state-to-state and depends on the number of adults in a household).  Furthermore, homebrewers are not allowed to _sell_ their beer.  Working out of a brewery may be perceived as a way to dodge taxes or production limits, which, well, the IRS does not like.  There is a grey area between what's "legal" and what's "prosecutable", which may be the bigger question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is talk to the OLCC.  I did that recently in relatioto a homebrewing class I'm teaching and they were very helpful.  My layman's opinion, based on the work I did helping get the OR homebrewing laws changed, is that it would be legal.  But I'm not a lawyer.  Contact the OLCC so neither you nor your friend get in trouble.